# Blank Display screen after upgrade to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, multiple-monitors, display, kde

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to 13.04 and after logging in my KDE plasma workspace I cannot change any monitor Display. It involves having the screen resolution at about 800x640 (I usually use 1600x1200) and not being able to add a 2nd monitor as usual.

> [image]

Is there anything I can do to solve it? I clearly cannot work and cannot upgrade anything else:

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  akonadi-facebook
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

System information:

```
$ cat /etc/*ease
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=13.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=raring
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 13.04"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="13.04, Raring Ringtail"
...
```

Comment: Go onto the Ubuntu IRC channel. #ubuntu

Comment: Did you tried to install the driver of your graphic card ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Do you have ?**

The KDE have two modules for the display/monitor configuration:

The older:

```
:~$ apt-cache show kde-workspace-randr
Package: kde-workspace-randr
Priority: optional
Section: universe/kde
...
Description-en: randr tools from kde-workspace
 Screen resize and rotate tools from KDE Workspace.

Homepage: http://www.kde.org/
```

The new one:

```
:~$ apt-cache show kscreen
Package: kscreen
Priority: extra
Section: universe/kde
...
Description-en: KDE monitor hotplug and screen handling
 The KDE multiple monitor support is trying be as smart as possible
 adapting the behavior of it to each use case making the configuration
 of monitors as simple as plugging them to your computer.
 .
 This package contains the modules and plugins for monitor hotplut and
 automatic screen handling.

Homepage: https://projects.kde.org/projects/playground/base/kscreen
```

Do you have one of those installed ?

**Is the KDE detecting the modules ?**

To list available KDE control modules type (konsole):

```
kcmshell4 --list
```

It is:

```
:~$ kcmshell4 --help
Usage: kcmshell4 [Qt-options] [KDE-options] [options] module 

A tool to start single KDE control modules

...

Options:
  --list                    List all possible modules
```

The new module:

> kcm_kscreen                - Manage and configure monitors and
>   displays

The Old module:

> randr                      - Resize and Rotate your display

You could try to launch them from the konsole:

```
kcmshell4 randr
```

or

```
kcmshell4 kscreen
```

Are they launching or do you get an error message.

If they are both installed and detected right the KDE system settings should show the options.

[image]

KScreen developer blog: http://www.afiestas.org/kscreen-1-0-released/

Kubuntu forums topic - 4.10.2 Monitor Configuration Disappears: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62326-4-10-2-Monitor-Configuration-Disappears

Kubuntu forums topic - Whither Size & Orientation in Display and Montior in systemsettings: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62197-Whither-Size-amp-Orientation-in-Display-and-Montior-in-system-settings

Kubuntu forums topic -How do I undo display resolution changes?: http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?62632-How-do-I-undo-display-resolution-changes

Comment: I have the new one, `kcm_kscreen`. I performed an `apt-get update` few days ago and must have been included in it, as now I can work with proper resolution and 2 monitors. I will give bounty as it was very helpful. --Also, to make the answer even better, I would suggest to add how to install each package.